# How to find $x$ when you have $y$ on a sinusoidal function without using a graphing calculator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$y=a \sin[b(x-c)]+d$

Let
$y=2,
a=2,
b=2,
c=2,
d=2,$

$2=2\sin[2(x—2)]+2$

$0=2\sin[2(x-2)]$

$0=\sin[2(x-2)] $

Now that’s where I’m stuck, and I have no idea what to do next to isolate $x$ since this is a new thing for me.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sin x=0$ then $x=n\pi$ with arbitrary $n\in\mathbb Z$.
$$\sin2(x-2)=0\implies 2(x-2)=n\pi\implies x-2=\frac{n\pi}2\implies x=\frac{n\pi}2+2$$

Comment: Ahh those are new things my school hasn’t taught yet. Anyways thanks sir! I’ll try to understand it